# VIsible Light Photodiode

Tags: led

I am repairing a coin sensor on a game called Treasure falls.  The coin slides down a slot and covers over some type of LED.  Usually on games like this there is an IR LED emitter and detector but this one only has a detector of some kind and it is sensing the presence and absence of visible light.  I have a known good working unit and I sketched out the schematics on the pcb attached to this device.  It is an Op Amp with a transistor and eight  resistors and a LED that shows when the sensor is covered or open to light. It compares a set voltage to the voltage in the circuit with the sensor LED. The sensor that the coin covers is a diode of some type.  It looks just like a standard 5mm clear LED.  I checked on a meter and I get a diode voltage drop of 1.5-2.5V depending on exposure to light.  When I measure the resistance with a meter I get 75 ohms when it is exposed to light and up to 300 ohms when covered.  What I have learned so far is that it is a light sensing photo detector but I can't seem to find out how to track one down with the resistance range I need.  That doesn't show on the data sheets I have seen.  Usually data sheets cover almost everything you need but perhaps I don't understand how this resistance is calculated.  Is this resistance supposed to be on data sheets or is there another way to figure out the resistance from the data sheet?  The manufacture won't provide the info on this unit and won't sell us the part. 
Thanks, 
Russ

Comment: This relates to closed question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/62529/2191. The answer there concerning LDRs is probably right. I suggest posting the circuit diagram and maybe a close-up photo of the "LED". Sometimes it is better to update a question (and get it reopened) than to ask a new question.

Comment: I can't seem to post a circuit diagram or a photo, it says I don't have enough reputation points. Wouldn't it better to keep this question since is has more details or how do I combine the questions.

Comment: You can edit the question to insert the URL of a link to an image (or just put it in a comment), then someone else with more rep will probably edit the image in-place for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry photo detectors do not work that way.

Like an ohm meter it generates a constant current except proportion to light. This means it will gen less voltage drop across the diodeand more thru the series circuit resistor (300R?) The cathode is reverse biased to V+ to reduce leakage. 3v?

photo diodes , PD are rated in [Amps per Watt] of light. Scaled to this small area , it is same as [mA/mW] 0.6 is an excellent value for a 5mm PD.
Assuming you are correct that it is IR, use this,  http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SFH229FA/475-1079-ND/607288

Comment: Isn't that Digikey part a IR Diode? I tried many IR Diodes and they didn't work. I need something that responds to visible light.

Comment: You gave voltage drop but no ref. to applied voltage On each polarity of the part.  LEDS are fwd biased low impedance like 50 ohm. Photodiodes are reverse biased high impedance current sources like MOhms . Something is missing in your circuit description.

Comment: Did u try here http://www.5starredemption.com/jumbo-treasure-parts.shtml